# How can i join three tables

Tags: mysql

How do I get user id and check if there are friends with a user.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wall 
inner join users on users.id=wall.Owner and request 
inner join users user.id=request.id 
ORDER BY wall.id_c DESC
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wall 
inner join users on users.id=wall.Owner 
join request on user.id=request.id 
ORDER BY wall.id_c DESC
```